# Download size bigger than raw file size android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I made these 2 apps and the results from the APK analyzer are different

[image: 1st app]

[image: 2nd app]

The problem is with the first app the **raw size** is smaller than the **download size** .I tried all the compression techniques from shrinking app in gradle size using

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

as well as removing any extra library dependencies in the gradle and in java code using code inspection.

Actually the 2nd app has substantially more data in every aspect even in gradle ,however it got compressed but the 1st one increased in size.

I actually tried to put the code of the 1st app in my 2nd and found out the size got smaller for no apparent reason.What can be the source of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there's nothing wrong with that?

As the info button says when you hover over it "Apk size is the minimum amount of space it will consume on the disk after installation". So maybe it will download something that in the best scenario won't be needed and thus won't be on disk.

If you're concerned about the size of your APK you should give APK Bundles a try (if your'e not doing this already). Our Apk download size went from 16 MB to 4.5 MB, and the steps to do it are really straight forward. You can get some info in [the oficial page](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/).

Hope it helps